# Setting up Karma in IntelliJ for Angular 2

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, karma-jasmine

For some reason, the angular 2 docs walk the user through installing Jasmine and then using an html page as a test runner. Yeah, uh, pass on that.

Karma was working great in the runner in IntelliJ/WebStorm using the original Angular.

Question here is if anyone has gotten this working yet. JetBrains has a few things about supporting Angular 2 but did not see mention of Karma.

Comment: See [ng2-test-seed](https://github.com/juliemr/ng2-test-seed).

Comment: @EricMartinez add that as an answer.. it's a good one!! thanks !

Comment: I really don't know how to elaborate the answer. I don't want to post a *check this site* answer. If it answers your question you're free to post it yourself.